# Initialising a category in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, objective-c-category

I'm writing a category for `UITextField` to include validation. I wish to change the text field's visual according to validation state (such as having an approved icon as its right view). For this, I keep a validation state property and wish to update the visual on its setter.

Here's what I have (UITextField+Validation.h)

```
@interface UITextField (Validation)

// Validator registration
- (void)addValidator:(id<HyValidator>)validator;

// Validation
- (void)validate;

@end
```

UITextField+Validation.m

```
@interface UITextField (Validation_Private)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * validators;
@property (nonatomic) HyValidationState validationState;

@end

@implementation UITextField (Validation_Private)

- (NSMutableArray*)validators
{
    if (self.validators == nil) {
        self.validators = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self.validators;
}

- (void)setValidators:(NSMutableArray *)validators
{
    self.validators = validators;
}

- (HyValidationState)validationState
{

}

- (void)setValidationState:(HyValidationState)validationState
{

}

- (void)addValidator:(id<HyValidator>)validator
{
    [[self validators] addObject:validator];
}

- (void)validate
{

}

@end
```

The question is: how do I initialise `validators` and `validationState`?

Comment: AFAIK, categories can't add properties, so how to initialize them is fairly moot.

Comment: They can't ?? But I don't get an error...

Comment: @AndréFratelli They can add properties, but they can't add storage.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the difference?

Comment: @AndréFratelli A property is a combination of a declaration of how you access stuff and, optionally, where that stuff is stored (i.e. an instance variables).  You can't add instance variables -- nor can `@property` synthesize instance variables -- on existing classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use categories for this.  Subclass instead.  Or, better yet, use the [UITextField's delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) to do the validation, as intended.

Using categories to extend the behavior of existing system classes is generally considered to be bad design.

By using delegation, you can decouple input validation from a specific input class and, thus, your validation can be easily re-used across other input mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add a storage to your class UITextField (simple ivar to hold the data). Since you don't have the code you can't extend the class. However in objective C you can achieve this using associated reference. ObjC Runtime comes handy helping you to attach a storage to your class and make you interact with the storage as if it was built in within the class.

An example of how to achieve this is found in Ole Begemann blog here http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/